# Find $a_1, \cdots, a_n \in [0, 1]$ so that pairwise sums are "most evenly spread"

Tags: real-analysis

Let $0 = a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \cdots \leq a_{n-1} \leq a_n = 1$, and $I = \{(i, j)| i, j \in \mathbb{Z} \wedge 1 \leq i < j \leq n\}.$

Loosely speaking, my question is: for what such non-descending sequences $a_1, \cdots, a_n \in [0, 1]$ are the pairwise sums $a_i + a_j, \forall (i, j) \in I$ are "most evenly spread"?

To make precise what I mean by "most evenly spread", suppose that $b_0 \leq \cdots \leq b_m$, where $m = {n \choose 2} - 1$, is the sequence obtained by sorting all the numbers $a_i + a_j, \forall (i, j) \in I$.

Let the variance of the $m$ numbers $c_k = b_k - b_{k-1}, \forall k \in \{1, \cdots, m\}$, be the measure of uniformity (the lower this variance, the more evenly spread the $b_i$ are).

Now I can rephrase my question more precisely:

> For what sequences $(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$ is the variance of the numbers $c_j$ (as defined above) minimized?

Comment: For any sequence $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ with $\max\{a_i\} > \min\{a_i\}$, we can divide all the $a_i$'s by $2$ and get a smaller variance of the $c_j$'s. So we need to impose some scaling constraint on the $a_i$'s.

Comment: @JimmyK4542: I've modified the definition of the $c_j$'s to take care of the issue you brought up.